# How to pass parameters thai language in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, thai

Thai characters are showing on the front end

I am trying to echo parameter วอลเปเปอร์ received from URL in `Codeigniter` but when I echo  it shows

```
%E0%B8%A7%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%A5%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%9B%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%9B%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%8C
```

My config file settings are `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '';` to allow all type of characters

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
echo urldecode ( $yourParameter );die;
```